# How to find the position of each bases in a fasta formatted sequence

Tags: perl

Please help to find the position of a fasta formatted sequence start position is 35658014 and end position is 35657750   in 3' and 5' regions respectively.And my sequence is in line by line.

Thanking you

Comment: You're going to have to give us way more information. Assume nobody knows what a fasta-formatted sequence looks like. Assume nobody knows what you mean by 3' and 5' regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get the actual gene code at those locations? I don't know Bio Perl but if it's just a string, here's what you can do:

First, this regex will remove the junk from the string:

```
$seq =~ s/^>*.+\n//;
```

And this one will remove the newlines

```
$seq =~ s/\n//g;
```

Then just use a regular perl substr: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html

```
my $section = substr($seq, $start-1, $end-$start);
```

That's assuming that your start and end count the first element as 1.

Of course, if you're already using bioperl (you probably should be), use the subseq function: http://doc.bioperl.org/releases/bioperl-1.0.1/Bio/Seq.html#POD8 . That page has enough information to read in a FASTA sequence and get a code from it based on start and end.